# I can't fit the table on the page

Tags: tables, page

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Sağa Değer(m) & Yukarı Değer(m) & Dönüklük açısı m0(deg) & Y yönündeki sapma değeri my(cm) & X yönündeki sapma değeri 
    mx(cm) & H yönündeki sapma değeri mz(cm) & Koordinat İsmi \\ \hline
    
    493285.05454 & 4497785.25251 &  161.390130 &    0.063687 &  0.057852 &  0.123302 &  FAKU \\ \hline
    
    495849.34756 &  4495798.21639 & 10.521446 & 0.095105 &  0.056880 &  0.178983 &  IZMT \\ \hline
    
    493343.14462 &  4497208.09875 & 176.672667 &    0.063316 &  0.057648 &  0.134021 &  BESY  \\ \hline
    
    493899.75903 &  4497854.43271 & 1.668609 &  0.062010 &  0.056385 &  0.134887 &  YMKH \\ \hline          
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) might be useful.

Comment: You could introduce line breaks in the column headers. Also, do you really need such long numbers?

Comment: yes i need.is it possible to do without cutting

Comment: You can also reduce the font size and the value of tabcolsep. If it still does not fit, you can also rotate the table to a landscape orientation. Apart from that, please make your code compilable( add the documentclass as well as the relevant packages).

Comment: please always post a complete small test document not just a fragment, you are asking how to make this fit but not saying how wide the page is which makes it hard to help, however the question is really a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144

Comment: will be fit on beamer page

Comment: I highly doubt it will be possible to fit auch a large table into a beamer frame while still keeping the contents of the table somewhat readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

The design of the page is unknown, so the proposal is based on guessing what is it like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|
                    *{2}{S[table-format=6.5]|}
                         S[table-format=3.6]|
                    *{3}{S[table-format=1.6]|}l|}
    \hline
{\makecell[b]{Sağa\\ Değer\\ (m)}} 
    &   {\makecell[b]{Yukarı\\ Değer\\ (m)}}
        &   {\makecell[b]{Dönüklük\\ açısı m0\\ (deg)}}
            &   {\makecell[b]{Y yönündeki\\ sapma değeri\\ my (cm)}}
                &   {\makecell[b]{X yönündeki\\ sapma değeri\\ mx (cm)}}
                    &   {\makecell[b]{H yönündeki\\ sapma değeri\\ mz (cm)}}
                        &   \makecell[b]{Koordinat\\ İsmi}     \\
    \hline
493285.05454 & 4497785.25251 & 161.390130 & 0.063687
    & 0.057852 & 0.123302 &  FAKU       \\ \hline
495849.34756 & 4495798.21639 &  10.521446 & 0.095105
    & 0.056880 & 0.178983 &  IZMT       \\ \hline
493343.14462 & 4497208.09875 & 176.672667 & 0.063316
    & 0.057648 & 0.134021 &  BESY       \\ \hline
493899.75903 & 4497854.43271 &   1.668609 &  0.062010
    & 0.056385 & 0.134887 &  YMKH       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```